# Bootstrap responsive grid breaks last row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, grid, window-resize

I have 8 total assets and I'm using bootstrap to create two rows of four that will break down to 4 rows of 2. However, when the rows respond, the 4th row breaks--the asset that's supposed to be on the left is set to the right, and the final asset is on a new row to the left. All divs are set the exact same as well. This code seems to be working on other pages, which is why I can't figure out why this page is breaking. [See image for visual explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDuiC.jpg) Please help!!

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">...</div>
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">...</div>
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">...</div>
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">...</div>
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">...</div>
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">...</div>
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">...</div>
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">...</div>
 <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please add full data? I think style is a problem which you gives.

Comment: Your HTML is correct, the problem may be with the live content you have in one of the the last two cells, or any specific floats or styling they may have.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">...</div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">...</div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">...</div>
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">...</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">...</div>
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">...</div>
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">...</div>
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">...</div>
</div>
```

Divided to two rows. Check it out.